# Why my Docker Jekyll build failed? Error: Permission denied

Tags: docker

My Docker Jekyll line to create a new scaffold

```
sudo docker run --rm -it --volume="$PWD:/srv/jekyll" jekyll/jekyll:4.0 jekyll new blog
```

I got permission denied

```
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux-musl]
jekyll 4.0.0 | Error:  Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /srv/jekyll/blog
```

My pwd

```
vagrant@gitlab:/$ pwd
/
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is right there: jekyll could not create the directory because it doesn't have permission.

The reason for this is that the jekyll user uses `UID 1000` https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/repos/jekyll/Dockerfile#L133, and this UID does not have write access to `/` in your host.

It doesn't matter if you use `sudo`, `sudo` is just to be able to run the docker service, but the container itself, uses UID 1000.

So, to solve this, just use a different host mount point where the user with UID 1000 have write access.